# Does Windows Speech Recognition allow the user to dictate in any program?

Tags: windows-speech-recognition

Does Windows Speech Recognition allow the user to dictate in any program, at least in theory? Or are there some types of programs that are not supported Windows Speech Recognition?

E.g., Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional allows the user to dictate in any program except for electronic health record programs.

Comment: *Any* program? Do we have to test them all?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator that's why I wrote types of programs

Comment: But how would one know that?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator user manual, experienced user's personal experience, understanding how the transcription is input into programs, etc

Comment: What research have you done into this? Have you done any or is this just a hypothetical question? Have you tried it? What experiences have you had?  Have you found any programs that don't work? Has every program you've tried so far worked or has there been problems? What problems? Are you just asking from a licence perspective or from a real world usage perspective? You should be very clear what *exactly* are you hoping to find out here.

Comment: @Mokubai I have been using Dragon for over 10 years. I use Windows 7, and thinking to move to 10. Dragon 12.5 often has issue with Windows 10, and Dragon 13+ cannot dictate in most applications. Knowing in which types of applications MSR works well help me decide whether to move to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

From https://redd.it/76h6f4:

> [Microsoft speech recognition] can enter text into virtually any text field. Some text fields (like those in embedded Java applications) may prove troublesome, but it should work in most areas.